# XML from Word Document issue

Tags: html, xml, xml-parsing, ms-word

I have an XML document that is inserted into from Word.  The details from the users are a little sketchy, but I believe the XML is inserted into by doing a Copy from Word.  The desired functionality being to insert copied MS Word formatted text into an xml document, store it in a DB for exportation later on.  The initial XML looks OK except for one strange tag.

```
 <?xml:namespace prefix = o ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" />
```

This tag has the effect of not allowing the XML to get parsed in Visual Studio 2010 and in IE 8.  After removing this tag another error appears.

```
End tag 'FONT' does not match the start tag 'P'. Error processing resource
```

It just appears that the Microsoft generated HTML inside the XML tags has issues.  I'm no XML expert....Is there an issue with MS generated HTML from Word?  And why does removing the  tag help?

Answer (score 0):

MS Word produces terrible markup -- storing in XML is the worst possible way this could be done. If you must keep the bad formatting data, a relational database would be a better solution, otherwise it will be necessary to remove formatting or manually correct it.

Comment: @John....yeah, the insertted formatted HTML is stored in a DB and then inserted into the XML.  Agreed, ugly!